# Not loading product by custom attribute

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a custom attribute that I created, but for some reason when I try to get the product by reference, I get the first product of the products collection and not the specific product. Am I doing something wrong, all the examples have the loadAttribute by SKU and it works, but when i use other attribute beside SKU it doesn't work. Any idea of the issue?

```
require '../../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);


$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('reference','F1515101');
```

Answer (score 0):

Method loadByAttribute always returns the first item of a product collection.

```
public function loadByAttribute($attribute, $value, $additionalAttributes = '*')
{
    $collection = $this->getResourceCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes)
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
        ->setPage(1,1);

    foreach ($collection as $object) {
        return $object;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So how can i make return the specific product?

Comment: Item of a product collection is already a product model. Only not loaded. You can do $_product->load() to get loaded product model